# Array sum rows and colums of an array

Tags: java, arrays

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, m, sumRows= 0, sumColumns= 0, i = 0, j = 0; //rows(n), Columns(m)
        n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Rows"));
        m = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Columns"));
        int[][] a = new int[n][m];
        int[] b = new int[n];
        int[] c = new int[m];
        for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type"
                        + "an int. A[" + i +"]" + "[" + j + "] = "));
                sumRows+= a[i][j];
                sumColumns+= a[j][i];

                if(j == a[i].length-1) {
                    b[i] = sumRows;
                    sumRows= 0;
                }

                if(i == a.length-1) {
                    c[j] = sumRows;
                    sumRows= 0;
                }
                System.out.println("Sum Rows: " + sumRows+ " Vector B" + i + ": " + b[i]);
                System.out.println("Sum Columns: " + sumColumns + " Vector C" + j + ": " + c[j]);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

So i have to sum the rows and colums and store them on two vectors, i have to store the sum of the rows in Vector B, and the sum of the columns in Vector C.
The sum of the rows works perfectly, but i can't get to work the sum of the columns.

Comment: Why `sumRows` and `sumColums`?  Why not just sum `a[i][j]` directly into `b[i]` and `c[j]`?

Comment: `sumaColumns` in Sysout looks like a typo.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao Oh yes, it's sumColumns.

Comment: If n!=m your code will not work. You will have columns less counted when rows is less then columns. And potential arrayindexoutofbound when rows greater then columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Rows"));
         int m = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Columns"));

        int[][] a = new int[n][m];
        int[] b = new int[n];
        int[] c = new int[m];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {

                a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type" + "an int. A[" + i + "]" + "[" + j + "] = "));

                b[i] += a[i][j];
                c[j] += a[i][j];
            }

        }

        // USED FOR PRINTING
        //  -------------------------
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Sum Row " + (i + 1) + " is " + b[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Sum Column " + (i + 1) + " is " + c[i]);
        }
        // -------------------------
    }
}
```

INPUT:

```
0   1   2   3   4   
5   6   7   8   9   
10  11  12  13  14  
15  16  17  18  19
```

OUTPUT:

```
Sum Row 1 is 10
Sum Row 2 is 35
Sum Row 3 is 60
Sum Row 4 is 85
Sum Column 1 is 30
Sum Column 2 is 34
Sum Column 3 is 38
Sum Column 4 is 42
Sum Column 5 is 46
```